# Detect a period of no activity within a specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my c# windows service i'm starting several threads. Each thread should dispose it's objects after a specific period of time with no activity.

I tried the System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer classes but they all raise the events on a different thread.

This is what's happining:

- create several threads during service.start
- each thread monitors a directory and activates a resource extensive function for every new file
- After a 1 hour of no activity inside the thread (no files are handled during that period)  i want to cleanup the resources inside that thread (structuremap, threadlocal classes)

Comment: Have you tried any method of synchronization? Some code could be useful.

Comment: This is a fairly decent way of doing what you need: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: If a thread does something reset the timer (is it called retrigger?). If the timer is up, dispose of it's objects. What do you mean by differt thread?

Comment: How are you starting the threads? Do you want each thread to dispose objects, or can you just cancel the thread. "no activity" in what? The Windows service? The thread? How does one tell if there is "no activity"?

Comment: I've added more info to the question. Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you monitoring the directory? At what method is your code waiting when it doesn't do anything?

Comment: There is built-in .NET functionality for doing this, known as a file system watcher: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: I'm using the built-in FileSystemWatcher class.. but this class is only triggered when a file is changed.. i need something that's being when nothing is changed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by *"a period of no activity"* you mean a thread that has been in the [WaitSleepJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx) for too long, you can interrupt such a thread by calling its [Interrupt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx):

```
var t = new Thread(WorkerThred);
t.Start();

// when the thread's been inactive for too long, kill it!
t.Interrupt();
```

This will cause a [ThreadInterruptedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadinterruptedexception.aspx) to be thrown in the target thread. Hence, you can catch the exception in order to dispose the thread's resources:

```
private void WorkerThred()
{
    try
    {
        DoWork();
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        DisposeResources();
    }
}
```

Now you need some way of tracking the amount of time each thread stays inactive. For instance, create a method that all threads **must** call before going to sleep or waiting on a mutex:

```
public static void UpdateLastActiveTime()
{
    var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
    if (!lastActiveTime.ContainsKey(t))
        lastActiveTime.Add(t, DateTime.Now);
    else
        lastActiveTime[t] = DateTime.Now;
}

private static Dictionary<Thread, DateTime> lastActiveTime;
```

Finally, to check for how long a specific thread has been inactive, call the following method:

```
public static TimeSpan GetInactiveTime(Thread t)
{
    // if thread isn't sleeping anymore update its time
    if (t.ThreadState != ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
        lastActiveTime[t] = DateTime.Now;
    return DateTime.Now - lastActiveTime[t];
}
```

I believe that using this pattern you will be able to create a thread manager class that meets your requirements.